# Throw new Exception and have a block where one catches any exception

Tags: java

```
private WebElement findElementByXpath(WebDriver driver, String xpath) throws WebElementNotFoundException, HopelessAccountException {

    WebElement element = null;

    try {
        element = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(dirationInSeconds))
                .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(xpath)));
    } catch (TimeoutException timeoutException) {
        loggingService.timeMark("findElementByXpath", "TimeoutException");
        throw new WebElementNotFoundException();
    } catch (UnhandledAlertException alertException) {
        loggingService.timeMark("findElementByXpath", "alertException");

        final String LIMITS_EXHAUSTED_MESSAGE = "Not enough limits!";
        String message = alertException.getMessage();

        if (message.contains(LIMITS_EXHAUSTED_MESSAGE)){
            throw new HopelessAccountException(); // Attention.
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Mustn't be here.
        loggingService.timeMark("findElementByXpath", e.getMessage());
        driver.quit();
        System.out.println("QUIT!");
        System.exit(0);
    }


    loggingService.timeMark("findElementByXpath", "end. Xpath: " + xpath);

    return element;
}
```

See the line that I commented as "Attention".

I have caught the exception where there is not enough limits any more. And I throw the exception that the account is hopeless.

But it is immediately caught by just after the next few lines. Namely where I commented "Mustn't be here".

I would like to preserve this catching any exception. At least for debugging purpose.

Can I both throw HopelessAccountException and preserve the "catch Exception" block?

Comment: Are you sure that is what happens, and it is not another exception that is caught? The `throw new HopelessAccountException()` should not be caught by the third catch block, because it is not inside the `try` block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always modify your `Exception` block to rethrow `e` if it is an instance of `HopelessAccountException`:

```
} catch (Exception e) {

    if (e instanceof HopelessAccountException) throw e;  // preserves original stack trace

    // Mustn't be here.
    loggingService.timeMark("findElementByXpath", e.getMessage());
    driver.quit();
    System.out.println("QUIT!");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

However as @fishinear indicates, in your posted code the `Exception` block would not be reached as a result of the throw of `throw new HopelessAccountException()` - if your actual code looked more like:

```
    try {
        try {
            System.out.println("In A()");
            // do something to cause an exception E3 (e.g. UnhandledAlertException)
            throw new E3();
        } catch (E3 e3) {  // UnhandledAlertException
            System.out.println("In E3 catch");
            throw new E1(); // HopelessAccountException
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("In Exception catch");
        if (e instanceof E1) throw e; // rethrow HopelessAccountException
        System.out.println("e: "+e);
    }
```

Then the test-and-rethrow is possible.

Then when you rip out your debugging "try block" your code would behave the same (for the HopelessAcountException).

Answer (score 0):

in your code that calls findElementByXpath(…) you could catch the broad Exception type there. This means in your findElementByXpath(…) method you could just handle the known exceptions and anything else could be captured in calling code